# Can neurons divide if somehow centrioles are introduced in nerve cells?

Tags: neurology

I am a biology student, so i know that centrioles are required for cell division, and i also know that nerve cells lack centrioles.

My question is that if somehow compatible  centrioles were introduced to the nerve cells, would their division be possible?

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! I think it would be helpful for people to know your understanding of mitosis and meiosis. Since you say you are a biology student, how much of cell division have you studied?

Comment: Please read about cell division and what happens there first and then rephrase your question. Adding centrioles alone wouldn't certainly be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Induced Pluripotent Cells
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_pluripotent_stem_cell?wprov=sfla1

You should probably look into this. This introduces what is called iPSCs, which are stem cells derived from adult cells.

What it is is that  they use signals that are found in embryonic cells, and the adult cells revert from their differentiated form into cells that can become virtually anything.